# Personality Insight Error

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dell.ora, PID: 24491
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.execute(WatsonService.java:122)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.executeRequest(WatsonService.java:183)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v2.PersonalityInsights.getProfile(PersonalityInsights.java:119)
at com.example.dell.ora.AnalyzerFragment.onCreateView(AnalyzerFragment.java:39)
```

I am trying to run personality insight from checking the docs I have this in my fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_analyzer, container, false);
        PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("", "");
        service.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api");
        EditText content=  x.findViewById(R.id.content);
        TextView output=  x.findViewById(R.id.output);
//        String text = content.getText().toString();
        String text =getResources().getString(R.string.demo);
        Profile profile = service.getProfile(text);
        System.out.println(profile);
        return x;
    }
```

And to do this I inserted in my gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:2.10.0'
```

Has anybody encountered this error?Can sb make evident what am I making wrong?Thank You in advance!

Comment: make sure you use the new version of the SDK. 2.10.0 it's very old.
See https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk

Comment: @GermanAttanasio how can I output it the json object into a text if I am inside a thread

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android but you can get the JSON string with `profile.toString()`.

Comment: doesnt work that way,I created a async task throws unknown error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){Profile profile = service.getProfile(text);
}).start();
```

Or use an async task. You must only initialize layouts and Views in your `onCreateView`. All other object initializations must be done in your `onActivityCreated`

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      final  String text =getResources().getString(R.string.demo);

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Profile doInBackground(Void... params) {

        PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights();
                            service.setUsernameAndPassword("", "");
        service.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api");

        Profile profile = service.getProfile(text);
       return profile;
               }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Profile profile) {
                    super.onPostExecute(profile);

        TextView output =  x.findViewById(R.id.output);
                 output.setText(profile.toString())
           }
              }.execute();

}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_analyzer, container, false);
        EditText content=  x.findViewById(R.id.content);
        TextView output =  x.findViewById(R.id.output);
//        String text = content.getText().toString();
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: in their documentation it is not written

Comment: Use an `async` or create a new `thread`. It's the way things are done on android since android 3, you can't do any network activity on the main thread or else the OS will throw a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception.

Comment: let me try tomorrow and I will let you know

Comment: Niza Thank You if could give me help with another question It would be great

Comment: Niza what if I want to output that Json in my android how can I do it?

Comment: @Ora, you have to use an object serializers and deserializers such as `Gson`

Comment: I was actually looking for a `TextView output... output.setText(profile.toSting());`however this doesn't work

Comment: how can I do the same with an async task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169649/discussion-between-niza-siwale-and-ora).